# Decoding and decompressing a file without using any file path

Tags: java

I am trying to decode a file and decompress  it .Input is a GZIP file encoded in base 64 encoding .But facing problems to do the code as I cant use any file path in my code as this is the requirement.

Comment: `in my code` Well, then show it

Comment: Java literally never asks you for a File when you try to decompress GZIP input. We will not be able to guess why you started to believe you need one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you try and be more specific about what exactly you are trying to do and where you are hitting road blocks? Ideally, you could create a [mcve] to demonstrate you issue.

Comment: So, assuming you've decoded the base64 data, you'll want to send it through a `ZipInputStream`

Comment: I faced the problem and then solved it as I have given below.Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

//** import statements

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
```

The following piece of code helps to decode and decompress a file without using a file path.

***Fist I am encoding a tar file:***

```
 String GZIP_NEW_FILE = "C:\\Users\\xyz\\Desktop\\Tar\\Final.tar.gz";
```

//**encoding a tar file**

```
private static String encodeFileToBase64Binary(String fileName) throws IOException {
            File file = new File(fileName);
            byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file));
            return new String(encoded);
        }
```

//**decoding a tar file**

```
private static byte[] decodeFileToBase64Binary(String base64String) throws IOException {

            return Base64.decodeBase64(base64String);
        }
```

//**decompressing a decoded gzip file**

```
public static String deCompressGZipFile(byte [] decodedBytes) 
        throws IOException{

      InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedBytes);
      GZIPInputStream gZIPInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(is);
      InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(gZIPInputStream);
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
      StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
      String readed;
      while ((readed = in.readLine()) != null) {
          sb.append(readed);
      }
      gZIPInputStream.close();
      return sb.toString().substring(sb.toString().indexOf("{"));
       }
```